# Sort Order of Stacked Bars in VegaLite

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

i have created a aggregate sum stacked bar chart in vegalite and i want the sequence of inside small bar(small blocks) in stack ascending order

for example in this chart -> [editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUARgBYQBO08IAcgKwCMdAzAIIgA0IAxgPYremUAxAHY6zACwARSexABLAHZg5sOCAC2m2cnQZ4dcRzlgw8RgF82hEuSiVadGi1k8%20AtSLFSZRpSsqa6tqomPqMRibwwpbWZBRqDk6sHK78QgBsNJLiAKIAYrKKyqogAA7lwbr6dBGmcAwxIMRxdgn0TMlcvGkemdn5hX4l5aWVofUADLVhjc229vRJLt3uIIIAQgBMzMwAnADCg8WUCqdjepPT9eKzNvHU7c4pK0K76Xl0OZtH-mqk-%20d4LsrnRolYmndWg9HE8um4hMJGOl1sxhD8SlBMYC4MD5JF6rtbi0FjDOqlVoJ9mJmHk0b5jmoIEzsQAOK6bOhE%20ZtBiw8lCLY7A7ok5nDg6cZsvF1TabLn3BwdZbwjyI5GokVqTF2cUhC5S4wym7guYKx5kl4eKk7WmakBM2C6qpwA34zY0eVQxJ8y1rZiMHKMPIsu0Ad3D2OE7JZnpJS2eKrWuzy%20Ty33pvxAAHMc9jDNL4OI5SbISSlQmemt0ukvsJ1nbOI3seEC3AnLGeeW4ZXBDlmJJGJIQxmSqcFNjNld0hYS8SefHuxThNXhNI7SgNxOpx7Z9zoQv%20b0a5s6w2m07xpPW8IJh3oV3D2tJMx9oP0-IhpQN5uLxcr4aokJXczV5C1E0Ef1A2DMMI1-eB-3xFlb2Ar1zWVHtk1Td8ikzHMsy3VsWQsABdSwQEQHgFE4eJ8BAUNjCgIgogmKYQCIDA5CzIhWkYGhWPUMgAGt4FAKAAE9SguJoyFkLAoFIbhBKkggUAgThhLIjAqO4ZQFHwhAQCgbheCgORRjgWiADM5AwFA6ghYlGms2z7Jw2AnJsuzKAlPRzGIjgAA8RPtHNSAwLNoCkrA0CCDhnK8tQfJAMixOC%20L7NNHVDIkqSFG4dRFFQWT%20ChABaIKyMPUB0soNzZOolALlAcg9KakAarUflzG67rSKAA) i have sorted the sum in descending order and by default the order of each value in it comes as alphabetically ascending(aaa then ccc then ggg then lll) but i want that also on the basis of ascending order of values in it (i.e. by the VALUE column present in data by which we have find the sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? You need an order encoding.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#71A4DD",
        "india": "mmm",
        "value": 14,
        "idd": 3
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#71A4DD",
        "india": "mmm",
        "value": 13,
        "idd": 7
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#65D4EF",
        "india": "ppp",
        "value": 11,
        "idd": 11
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#65D4EF",
        "india": "ppp",
        "value": 10,
        "idd": 13
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#B2AA9C",
        "india": "nnn",
        "value": 10,
        "idd": 14
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#96F1E2",
        "india": "rrr",
        "value": 9,
        "idd": 17
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#736BA7",
        "india": "ttt",
        "value": 9,
        "idd": 19
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#C1AAF7",
        "india": "aaa",
        "value": 8,
        "idd": 21
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#B2AA9C",
        "india": "nnn",
        "value": 8,
        "idd": 22
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#736BA7",
        "india": "ttt",
        "value": 8,
        "idd": 24
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#C1AAF7",
        "india": "aaa",
        "value": 8,
        "idd": 25
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#A3E3F8",
        "india": "www",
        "value": 7,
        "idd": 28
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#9FEFF2",
        "india": "ggg",
        "value": 4,
        "idd": 42
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#66E27B",
        "india": "ccc",
        "value": 3,
        "idd": 53
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#EAD3D8",
        "india": "nnn",
        "value": 2,
        "idd": 63
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#7667DD",
        "india": "lll",
        "value": 2,
        "idd": 65
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5153A",
        "color": "#66E27B",
        "india": "ccc",
        "value": 2,
        "idd": 70
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#DAC3D2",
        "india": "llll",
        "value": 2,
        "idd": 79
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#A3E3F8",
        "india": "www",
        "value": 2,
        "idd": 80
      },
      {
        "bharat": "N5113A",
        "color": "#9FEFF2",
        "india": "ggg",
        "value": 2,
        "idd": 83
      }
    ]
  },
  "width": 700,
  "height": 350,
  "mark": {"type": "bar", "stroke": "black"},
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": [{"field": "bharat"}, {"field": "india"}, {"field": "value"}],
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "value"},
    "order": {"sort": "descending", "field": "value"},
    "y": {"field": "bharat", "type": "nominal"},
    "color": {"field": "india", "scale": {"range": {"field": "color"}}}
  }
}
```